# chef ssl error while bootstarping from workstation from apache server

Tags: apache, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to run a cookbook from my chef workstation and I'm getting this error

```
 Starting first Chef Client run...
 Starting first Chef Client run...
 [2015-05-22T21:00:45+05:30] WARN: 
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

 ``
   # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
 ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

   # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
   verify_api_cert true


To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the^M
 `knife ssl check` command like so:
knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Starting Chef Client, version 11.18.6
 ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/nodes/nodename, retry 2/5
 ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/nodes/nodename, retry 3/5
 ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/nodes/nodename, retry 4/5
] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/nodes/nodename, retry 5/5
```

when I did curl

```
curl  https://localhost/nodes/nodename
```

I got

```
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

but for

```
knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb
```

the status is successful from my server

I added ssl_verify_mode :verify_peerto in my workstation knife.rb file then also the issue is same please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try running the ssl fetch command on your chef client:

```
knife ssl fetch -c /etc/chef/client.rb
```

Source:

- http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/